# How to load only .txt file using SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, file

I have different types of files in a folder. But I want to load only text (`.txt`) files using raw SQL Server queries.

Suppose I have a folder like `D:\NewDataFolder` where I have different types of files like pdf, CSV, word, txt, and many others. But I need to load only the text (`.txt`) files.

I already tried with the following code which loads all types of files that exist in that folder:

```
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @fileDir VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @files TABLE ([Id] INT IDENTITY, [FileName] VARCHAR(1000));

SET @fileDir = 'D:\NewDataFolder';

SET @command = 'dir /b ' +  @fileDir;   

INSERT INTO @files 
    EXECUTE xp_cmdshell @command;

SELECT * 
FROM @files 
WHERE [FileName] IS NOT NULL 
  AND [FileName] <>'File Not Found'
```

Comment: Does just `SET @fileDir='D:\NewDataFolder\*.txt';` work?

Comment: @KenY-N, thanks a lot it works.

Comment: How can a `DIR` command `LOAD` a `.txt` file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Ken Y-N comment, I got the answer. And just need to add a file extension like the following.

```
SET @fileDir='D:\NewDataFolder\*.txt';
```